# How to make the Facebook Like Box responsive?

Tags: css, widget, responsive-design

I am using the Facebook like box code in my [side bar](http://noahsdad.com/) by pasting the Facebook code into a text widget. My theme is responsive, and I'd like to get the like box to resize correctly. I found this [tutorial](http://inspectelement.com/tutorials/how-to-make-the-facebook-like-box-responsive/) but he says the way he is doing it, isn't "fully responsive" so I didn't know if there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 120):

NOTE: this answer is obsolete. See [the community wiki answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15116982/364446) for an up-to-date solution.

---

I found this Gist today and it works perfectly: https://gist.github.com/2571173

(Many thanks to https://gist.github.com/smeranda)

```css
/* 
Make the Facebook Like box responsive (fluid width)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ 
*/

/* 
This element holds injected scripts inside iframes that in 
some cases may stretch layouts. So, we're just hiding it. 
*/

#fb-root {
    display: none;
}

/* To fill the container and nothing else */

.fb_iframe_widget, .fb_iframe_widget span, .fb_iframe_widget span iframe[style] {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: nice easy solution but there is no need to have the browser render the #fb-root element and then hide it in the CSS. Just delete the element all together.

Comment: Keep in mind that the pictures of the wall have a certain size which results in a minimum size of the like box.

Comment: Only issue I'm still seeing here, is with an iPhone, if you scroll through the news feed and load more posts, they load much bigger and break out of the layout. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't forget to set data-width="100%" in the FB DIV itself

Comment: NOT OBSOLETE!  
Putting the script into an iFrame may not be feasible, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 28):

Colin's example for me clashed with the like button. So I adapted it to only target the Like Box.

```
.fb-like-box, .fb-like-box span, .fb-like-box span iframe[style] { width: 100% !important; }
```

Tested in most modern browsers.

Comment: Worked nicely for me thanks @sovarn had been trying to write a jquery hack before.

Comment: Honestly.. Thanks a lot. I would cuddle you if I could! Nice fix to a problem that was really bugging me.

Comment: works nice, what does the "iframe[style]" exactly do?

Comment: +1, works nicely in conjunction with media queries specifying a few pre-set `max-height` values at various breakpoints.

Comment: @wutzebaer, `iframe[style]` simply targets any `iframe` elements with a `style` attribute set (blank or otherwise). i.e. it'll ignore  `<iframe src="..."></iframe>` but will successfully target `<iframe src="..." style=""></iframe>`.

Answer (score 26):

NOTE: Colin's solution didn't work for me. Facebook may have changed their markup. Using `*` should be more future-proof.

Wrap the Like box with a div:

```
<div id="likebox-wrapper">
    <iframe src="..."></iframe> <!-- likebox code -->
</div>
```

and add this to your css file:

```
#likebox-wrapper * {
   width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use an iFrame to embed the likebox in the first place? .fb-like-box{width: 100% !important;} is all I needed. <div class="fb-like-box" ... </div> inside a <div class="col-md-6"></div>

Answer (score 7):

As of August 4 2015, the native facebook like box have a responsive code snippet available at Facebook Developers page.

You can generate your responsive Facebook likebox here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

This is the best solution ever rather than hacking CSS.

Comment: By ticking of "Adapt to plugin container width" the like box will only change width on page load (not by resizing the browser window). To prevent the design from messing up on window resize (or tablet orientation change) you could also trigger a refresh or use width:100%; overflow-x:hidden; max-width:500px; (on the surrounding div)

Answer (score 3):

The answer you're looking for as of June, 2013 can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/dineshcooper/2111366

It's accomplished using jQuery to rewrite the inner HTML of the parent container that holds the facebook widget.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The gist no longer works for me as of July 2014. It looks like facebook added hardcoded styles with `width="xxxpx"` inside the iframe which is breaking this method.

Answer (score 0):

None of the css trick worked for me (in my case the fb-like box was pulled right with "float:right"). However, what worked without any additional tricks is an IFRAME version of the button code. I.e.:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=..." 
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
        style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:71px; height:21px;" 
        allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

(Note custom width in style, and no need to include additional javascript.)

Comment: Where does one generate this snippet, or what's the full source value supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this on Drupal 7 with the " fb_likebox" module (https://drupal.org/project/fb_likebox).  To get it to be responsive. Turns out I had to write my own Contrib module Variation and stripe out the width setting option. (the default height option didn't matter for me). Once I removed the width, I added the `<div id="likebox-wrapper">` in the fb_likebox.tpl.php.

Here's my CSS to style it:

```
 `#likebox-wrapper * {
  width: 100% !important;
  background: url('../images/block.png') repeat 0 0;
  color: #fbfbfb;
 -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
   -o-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
   border: 1px solid #DDD;}`
```