# How to make facebook likebox -widget have fluid (100%) width and work in iOS?

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design, facebook-likebox

Problem is that the Likebox -widget is not responsive by default.
It seems like I’m not the only one having this problem:

[How to make the Facebook Like Box responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656038/how-to-make-the-facebook-like-box-responsive)

https://gist.github.com/smeranda/2571173

https://gist.github.com/dineshcooper/2111366

http://jsREMOVETHISfiddle.net/dineshcooper/9YGVY/2/ (sorry about the removethis, but this is just one example with iOS-issues and not that important. so I won't include the code here)

Some of those solutions work, but for some reason the widget layout always breaks out of it’s container in iOS if widget width is set to 100%.

Problem example that works in desktop browsers but fail on iOS:

1. is this an iOS bug or Facebook like box -problem?
2. How would you fix it?